# compare _SESSION and saved _SESSION in php

Tags: php

is it ok to compare _POST to a later _POST in PHP ? If so how?

So the way the site I'm working on works, it loads all of the data into _POST, then the user can edit the data on the page that changes values in _POST.  So I want to compare and get the differences from the initial load and what is actually saved. Make sense?

Page loads with PHP  sets _POST info.
I want to _SNAPSHOT_POST = _POST
then when they click to save
compare the difference of _SNAPSHOT_POST and current _POST

Thoughts ?

Page loads with default data from DB :

```
  _POST - array(3) {
    ["save_data"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["check_id"]=>
    string(3) "710"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Michael"
  }
```

User makes a change :

```
  _POST - array(3) {
    ["save_data"]=>
    string(1) "999999"
    ["check_id"]=>
    string(3) "710"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Michael"
  }
```

User clicks Save Button:
Result  Array (of what has changed):

```
  array(1) {
    ["save_data"]=>
    string(1) "999999"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the SNAPSHOT_POST in a different key in session. When changes are made in new _POST, during submit check for the SNAPSHOT_POST variable stored in _SESSION. This is the PHP way.

Else Javascript is always there to handle this problems.

Comment: so you mean something like this:                  foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                    $_SESSION['snapshot'][$key] = $value;
                }

Comment: how do I compare ?

Comment: array_diff($_SESSION['snapshot'], $_POST);